# Creating actions and routes for tags and categories

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, categories, acts-as-taggable-on, controller-actions

I'm creating a blog for myself with Rails 3.2.5, and am trying to handle `tags` and `categories` properly.  I want to allow the user to click on a `link_to` with the tag name that brings them to other entries with the same tag and have the URL be `'root.com/tag/selected-tag'`.  For categories I'd like to have the same thing with the URL being `'root.com/category/selected-category'`.  I've already started on this and am using `acts_as_taggable_on` for tagging and a simple `text input` for the category (will become a `select input` when I decide what categories I want).

How would I go about handling this?  I've tried creating a controller for `tags` and `categories`, each with only an `index` action.  For `'tags#index'` I have:

```
@entries = Entry.order('created_at desc').tagged_with(params[:format]).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
```

and for each `tag`'s link I have:

```
= link_to tag, tag_path(tag)
```

For some reason the `tag` is being passed as the `:format`, that's why I've got `tagged_with(params[:format])`.

I have `'categories#index'` defined as:

```
@entries = Entry.order('created_at desc').where(:category => params[:format]).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
```

and the `category`'s link is:

```
  - entry.tag_list.each do |tag|
    = link_to tag, tag_path(tag)
```

Since the `tags` and `category` are being passed as the `:format` the URL's are appearing as `'root.com/tag.selected-tag'` and `'root.com/category.selected-category'`.

How would I go about handling `tags` and `categories` properly to achieve getting the URL's to appear as `'root.com/tag/selected-tag'` and `'root.com/category/selected-category'`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The below will probably do what you want:

In your routes:
`match 'tag/:tag' => 'tags#index', :as => :tag`

Then, when someone visits `example.com/tag/some-tag-here`, you can then access the tag within your controller through:
`params[:tag]`

you can link to your route by doing:

`link_to tag, tag_path(:tag => tag)`

An analogous solution should work for categories as well.